# Interesting layout weight behavior

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I've encountered some interesting behavior setting the weight of two views in a linear layout.

I have a horizontal Linear layout with `weightSum = 1`. It has two children views, `leftView` & `rightView`. I am making a horizontal bar graph by setting the weight of the views.

If I set the left view with a weight of `0.05` and the right view with a weight of `0.95` programmatically. The behavior presented in the UI will show the left view with taking up 95% of the width and the right view 5% of the width.

If I reverse it setting the `leftView` with `0.95` & the `rightView` with `0.05` the UI will present the `leftView` taking up 5% of the space (the way I wish it to be)

Does anyone have any insight to why this occurs?

```
float percentage= (float)(x * 100) / y; // (2000 * 100) / 40000 = 5

LinearLayout.LayoutParams leftViewParams = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        percentage/100f); // (5 / 100) = .05
leftView.setLayoutParams(leftViewParams);


LinearLayout.LayoutParams rightViewParams= 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
       (100 - percentage)/100f); //(100 - 5) / 100 = .95
rightView.setLayoutParams(rightViewParams);
```

However if I set the leftview to have a weight of .95 and the right view to have a weight of .05 the left view takes up 95% of the space while the right view only takes up 5%.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

BONUS XML - if I set `leftView` `layout_weight=0.05` and `rightView` `layout_weight=0.95` it displays correctly.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/core_dimen_16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/leftView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/rightView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#AAA" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When are you calling your code? You may need to call `requestLayout()` for the changes to take hold.

Comment: @ChrisStillwell haven't forgotten about your response and will give the `view.requestLayout()` a try when i get a chance. I am calling this code in the UI thread after a calling a service.

Comment: @ChrisStillwell `requestLayout()` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and everything is correct. There is no problem. I think that probably you make a little mistake.

I paid attention to your code and I noticed that you should change `remainingWeight` to `rightViewParams` in the line: `rightView.setLayoutParams(remainingWeight);`

I hope this will help.

Comment: I know everything is correct- it works and I don't understand why (purpose of question). `rightViewParams` and `remainingWeight` was an editing mistake to make the code more generic for easier reading for SO.

Comment: So now what is the problem. please explain more. thanks.

Comment: If you didn't read the problem why did you bother to respond?